# Displaying Multi-Dimension array data for suffling using fisher yates

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

im trying to shufing data from database using fisher yates, but doesnt work. the problem maybe on taking data form multi-dimesion array.

this is my code using php

```
require 'fyshuffle.class.php';
    function test($test){
    if(abs(min($test) - max($test)) > 1) return false;
    return true;
    }
    $hasil1=mysql_query("select * from tsoal where soalid='1'");
    $hasil2=mysql_query("select * from tsoal where soalid='2'");
    $hasil3=mysql_query("select * from tsoal where soalid='3'");
    $hasil4=mysql_query("select * from tsoal where soalid='4'");
    $row1 =mysql_fetch_array($hasil1);
    $row2 =mysql_fetch_array($hasil2);
    $row3 =mysql_fetch_array($hasil3);
    $row4 =mysql_fetch_array($hasil4);

    $array = array('one' => $row1, 'two' => $row2, 'three' => $row3, 'four' => $row4);

    $test = array();
    foreach ($array as $x => $y) {
        $test[$y] = 0;
    }
    $shuffle = new FYShuffle($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $result = $shuffle->fetch();
        $book=array();
        while ($result){
            $userid = $result{'soalid'};
            $book[$userid][$result{'pertanyaan'}] =  $row{'pilihan_a'};
            echo $userid;
            echo $book;
        }
    }
```

$result is Variabel for diplaying and suffling

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by saying it does not work. Please be specific in stating what part does not work and include any error output.

Comment: You also have a lot of undefined or unused variables in that code.